# Error on uploading laravel vendor folder to cpanel

Tags: php, laravel, cpanel

When I upload the vender folder in cpanel I get the following error:

> The file you uploaded, vendor.zip, contains a virus so the upload was canceled: Sanesecurity.Foxhole.Zip_bat.UNOFFICIAL FOUND.

What is the issue?

Comment: CPanel uses some virus scanners. It may had found something malicious in that file. Try to upload it via FTP or unzip the folder then upload it

Comment: this is common if your host sets up a kind of virus security check, you can use filezilla FTP client  or contact your host to do it for you, or run an SSH comand on your server , `composer update` - this would reinstall the vendor folder - i use this option most times, so as to save data when transfering from local host to server, tho the setup for achieving this is way longer than contacting your host :-)

Comment: thank you i fixed my problem using  ftp client..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My host doesn't provide **ssh access**. So, I uploaded the file using the **Filezilla FTP client**. And It work's.